# Why is MaterialAlertDialog so slow when measuring a custom view/layout?

Tags: android, performance, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, android-viewbinding

I'm working on a hobby project where I'm building a custom Bluetooth remote that can be configured using a companion native Android app. Everything is working just fine but I'm running into this weird performance issue with the `MaterialAlertDialog` using a custom layout and View Binding.
To be specific, when first showing the dialog, inflating, measuring, and then drawing the dialog takes quite a long time. According to some `systrace`s I've recorded, the UI hangs for about 1 to 2 seconds before rendering the next frame after starting the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` logic.

For context, this screenshot from Android Studio shows the UI I've built and this is the custom view for the `AlertDialog`.
[image: Android Studio Layout Screenshot]

These are the related libraries I'm using and their respective versions

```
Kotlin 1.4.30
AndroidX AppCompat 1.3.0-beta01
AndroidX ConstraintLayout 2.0.4
AndroidX Fragment KTX 1.3.0
Material Components 1.3.0
```

And here's the XML for this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingHorizontal="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="24dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyButtonPosition"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.ctrl.Overline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/edit_hotkey"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.ctrl.Headline6.Emphasis"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyButtonPosition"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyButtonPosition"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyButtonPosition" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyGroup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner_key_groups"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyKeyContainer"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyButtonPosition" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyKeyContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyGroup">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyKeyAlphanumeric"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
            android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:maxLength="1" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyKey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner_keys"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierShift"
        style="@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Outline.Narrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:text="@string/shift"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyGroup" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifiers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierShift">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierCtrl"
            style="@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Outline.Narrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ctrl" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierMeta"
            style="@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Outline.Narrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/meta" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierAlt"
            style="@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Outline.Narrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/alt" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierRShift"
        style="@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Outline.Narrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:text="@string/rshift"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierShift" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyRModifiers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifiers">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierRAlt"
            style="@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Outline.Narrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ralt" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierRMeta"
            style="@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Outline.Narrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rmeta" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/dialogEditPresetHotkeyModifierRCtrl"
            style="@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Outline.Narrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rctrl" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

To help keep my `Fragment`'s code clean, I've written a few Kotlin Extension functions to set up the `MaterialAlertDialog`, with ViewBinding, like I'm also using in my `Fragment`s.

```
class ViewBindingMaterialAlertDialogBuilder<VB : ViewBinding>(
    context: Context,
    viewBindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup?, Boolean) -> VB
) : MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context) {
    val viewBinding: VB by lazy {
        viewBindingInflater(LayoutInflater.from(context), null, false)
    }
}
inline fun <VB: ViewBinding> Context.customViewAlertDialogBuilder(
    noinline viewBindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup?, Boolean) -> VB,
    cancelable: Boolean = false,
    showManually: Boolean = false,
    init: ViewBindingMaterialAlertDialogBuilder<VB>.() -> Unit
) = ViewBindingMaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, viewBindingInflater).apply {
    setCancelable(cancelable)
    init()
    if (!showManually) show()
}
inline fun <VB : ViewBinding> ViewBindingMaterialAlertDialogBuilder<VB>.initCustomView(
    init: VB.() -> Unit
) = setView(viewBinding.apply(init).root)
inline fun MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.positiveButton(
    @StringRes text: Int,
    automaticallyDismiss: Boolean = true,
    crossinline action: () -> Unit
) = setPositiveButton(text) { dialog, _ -> if (automaticallyDismiss) dialog.dismiss(); action() }
inline fun MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.negativeButton(
    @StringRes text: Int,
    automaticallyDismiss: Boolean = true,
    crossinline action: () -> Unit
) = setNegativeButton(text) { dialog, _ -> if (automaticallyDismiss) dialog.dismiss(); action() }
inline fun MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.neutralButton(
    @StringRes text: Int,
    automaticallyDismiss: Boolean = true,
    crossinline action: () -> Unit
) = setNeutralButton(text) { dialog, _ -> if (automaticallyDismiss) dialog.dismiss(); action() }
inline fun MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.show(
    crossinline onShow: AlertDialog.() -> Unit
) = create().apply {
    setOnShowListener { onShow(it as AlertDialog) }
}.show()
```

And then I use these as follows in my `Fragment`.
**NOTE**: The actual code described in the comments below had been commented out at the time of recording the `systrace` further down. This was done to make sure the initialization code wasn't impacting performance or skewing data.

```
context.customViewAlertDialogBuilder(DialogEditPresetHotkeyBinding::inflate, showManually = true) {
    initCustomView {
        //Populate TextView and set two adapters for the Spinners
    }
    positiveButton(R.string.save) {
        //Persist entered value to device
    }
    negativeButton(R.string.discard) {} //Simply dismisses
    neutralButton(R.string.clear) {
        //Persists default value to device
    }
    show {
        /*
        Set OnItemSelectedListeners for Spinners
        Add TextWatcher for EditText
        Check if entered values are valid (else disable Save button)
         */
    }
}
```

After then cleaning, building, and running my app on a physical device (LG G6 H870), I get the following `systrace`.
**NOTE**: I restarted my phone before running this trace to make sure the least amount of apps possible were running in the background to not skew results.
[image: AlertDialog Systrace]

For good measure (pun intended) and as a performance comparison, I used the same layout in a separate `Fragment`

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {
    private var viewBinding: DialogEditPresetHotkeyBinding? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        viewBinding = DialogEditPresetHotkeyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return viewBinding?.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        viewBinding = null
    }
}
```

And the `systrace` when navigating to this `Fragment`.
**NOTE**: I force-stopped the app from Settings, then ran it after again cleaning and building
[image: Fragment Systrace]

---

So, after all that, my question boils down to:

**Why is inflating and measuring a custom layout in an `AlertDialog` so much slower than when using a `Fragment`?**

I know there probably are some optimizations possible within my XML, but it still takes over a second to first show the `AlertDialog`, compared to half that when using a `Fragment`.
This is a best-case scenario as I've seen it go as high as **1.7** seconds with some apps running in the background. This is way higher than the 700ms Android 'jank' threshold, so I'm also getting `Davey!` log messages, skipped frames, halted ripple animations, etc.

P.S. I know this is a very long question, thank you for reading :)

---

**EDIT 1**
Adding my `styles.xml` and `themes.xml`, nothing but colors and some dimensions, I like to keep it simple, plus the fact that I'm not a designer :)

`styles.xml`

```
<resources>
    <style name="Widget.ctrl.AlertDialog" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="backgroundInsetTop">@dimen/mtrl_alert_dialog_background_inset_start</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.ctrl.Button.Outline.Narrow" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">64dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.ctrl.Button.Dialog" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.ctrl.Button.Dialog.Positive">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dialog_button_positive</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.ctrl.Button.Dialog.Negative">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorError</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorError</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.ctrl.Button.Dialog.Neutral">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.ctrl.Headline6" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextNormal</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.ctrl.Headline6.Emphasis">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextEmphasis</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.ctrl.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextNormal</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.ctrl.Subtitle1.Emphasis">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextEmphasis</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.ctrl.Body1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextNormal</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.ctrl.Body1.Emphasis">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextEmphasis</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.ctrl.Body2" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextNormal</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.ctrl.Overline" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Overline">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextNormal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShapeAppearance.ctrl.40dpCircle" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="cornerSize">20dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`themes.xml`

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.ctrl" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/colorOnBackground</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorSurface</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/colorError</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">@color/colorOnError</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorBackground</item>

        <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.ctrl.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.ctrl.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
        <item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/Widget.ctrl.AlertDialog</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Dialog.Positive</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Dialog.Negative</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ctrl.Button.Dialog.Neutral</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
I tried using the AndroidX `AsyncLayoutInflater` to see if it makes a difference. It does...
...but it feels even worse. What ends up happening is that the ripple animation no longer hangs halfway through, instead, it completes and a second later, a dialog finally pops up. I feel this is confusing to a user as one part of the interface feels responsive but there's a lot of lag on the dialog showing due to the long measuring. So I don't see this as a fix.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme that doesn't extend the app theme, or launching from an Activity with a transparent theme?

Comment: @MarkKeen I added the styles.xml and themes.xml to my question. Shouldn't be anything weird as I'm extending from the MaterialComponents themes and just changing some colors. Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Also, the `Theme.ctrl` theme is applied in the Manifest to the single, main `AppCompatActivity` whichs hosts AndroidX Fragments using Navigation Components

Comment: As a test can you remove the custom style and just inherit from stock theme and see of that makes a difference. Probably not, bit I've experienced lag on inflation simply for using a custom theme instead of inherited.

Comment: @MarkKeen I ran it again with the default `Theme.MaterialComponents` (restart device, clean, build, run) and it took **1.469s** to open up the dialog. Running without a theme immediately crashed as I'm using Material views pretty much everywhere. Also, I realized that this wouldn't explain the discrepancy between the Dialog and Fragment, but a great tip still, hadn't thought of it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it turned out my device I was testing on was just very slow...
I switched from an LG G6 to a OnePlus 8T and the dialog now pops up almost instantaneously, oh well...